# Bash If Else statement inside one line command

Tags: bash, if-statement, case

I've got a case:

```
case $1 in
  "start") exec docker-compose up ;;
  "check-types") docker-compose run --rm myapp mypy --config-file=mypy.ini $2;;
  "help" | *) print-help ;;
esac
```

I would like to replace `$2` written in `"check-types"` with an `if` statment which would state something similar to:

```
if [[ $2 ]]; then
  $2
else
  .
fi
```

Is that possible in one line of bash?

Example of the desired behavior:

- writing `./cli check-types` executes `docker-compose run --rm myapp mypy --config-file=mypy.ini .`
- writing `./cli check-types app/test` executes `docker-compose run --rm myapp mypy --config-file=mypy.ini app/test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `:-` operator to specify a default value if `$2` is null or unset.

```
case $1 in
  "start") 
    exec docker-compose up ;;
  "check-types")
    docker-compose run --rm myapp mypy --config-file=mypy.ini "${2:-.}";;
  "help" | *)
    print-help ;;
esac
```

(In general, though, `bash` does not have a conditional expression.)